# In Entity Framework 6 how can I create a one to many mapping with a navigation property on the other side?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

My domain model is that a `Trade` can have many `TradeLeg`s. I am trying to use the following mappings.

Trade Mapping

```
HasKey(t => t.TradeId);
Property(t => t.TradeId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
     .HasColumnName("TradeId");                                      
Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
Property(t => t.CounterpartyId).HasColumnName("CounterpartyId");
Property(t => t.Quantity).HasColumnName("Quantity");
Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");

HasMany(t => t.TradeLegs);

ToTable("Trade");
```

Trade leg mapping

```
HasKey(t => t.TradeLegId);
Property(t => t.TradeLegId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    .HasColumnName("TradeLegId");                                      
Property(t => t.TrdId).HasColumnName("TrdId"); // FK  back to trade
Property(t => t.Ordinal).HasColumnName("Ordinal");
Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");

ToTable("TradeLeg");
```

When I try to select some trades I get the Excpetion.

> Invalid column name `Trade_TradeId`.

I can make it work by adding a navigation property on TradeLeg back to trade and adding `.WithRequired(u => u.Trade).HasForeignKey(u =>u.TrdId)` to my `HasMany()` mapping on the `Trade` object.

However, I don't want to have a navigation property on `TradeLeg` back to `Trade`. I just want to have an int FK property (`TrdId`) on `TradeLeg`. I also noticed that if I use `TradeId` instead of `TrdId` as the FK property on `TradeLeg` that it will also works because of the default rules. Is there a way to tell EF the name of FK field on the other side of the `HasMany()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping should work for you `Trade` object using `HasMany()`. Something like below should work.

```
HasMany(t => t.TradeLegs)
    .WithRequired() //use WithOptional for optional no need to specify the mapping on the other side.
    .HasForeignKey(leg => leg.TrdId);
```

I just tested this on EF6 on one of my mapping objects and seems to work.

This same concept can work the other way when you would like a One-to-Many on the child without a navigation property on the parent such as

```
HasRequired(x => x.Property)
    .WithMany() //no need to specify the navigation property on the other side
    .HasForeignKey(x=> x.ForeignKeyProperty);
```

Comment: thanks very much for the quick response. I've tried using empty with clauses on both sides in the case where navigation properties exist on both side and everything seems to work as expected. Is there anything to be gained by adding the reverse navigation property to the with clause? if not I may as week leave the with clause  empty always.

Comment: IMO I try and express exactly how the navigation properties are setup and by ommitting them I am telling other developers (and myself) that there is no reverse navigation property on purpose. Now there are cases when the reverse may have multiple properties that "could" navigate back. Say an entity has a navigation property to two entities of the same type. This wont work without specifying your actual properties. An example would be two (optional) parent entities for a child. If you have `ParentA` and `ParentB` both of the same types, then without the navigation property setup this wont work.

Comment: Point taken about communicating the intent, but in the case you mention I was thinking it should be possible to have navigation properties to both parents and still have empty with clauses in the mappings, but thinking further may the problem comes when you try to do queries with linq and you want to refer to related entities. Is that what you mean?